# Is there a way to pass a function to another function in the render return?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to pass a function to another function.

The first function downloads some JSON data then returns it (this works). The next function is supposed to map the JSON data to HTML code (this does not work).

I have nested the first function call within the second function, but there is no result in my browser and React "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined." But shouldn't the map be defined, since the inner function is evaluated first?

```
import React from 'react';
import axios, { post, get } from 'axios';

class Line {
    constructor(json) {
        this.id = json.id
        this.name = json.name
        this.html = <p>{this.name}'s ID is {this.id}.</p>
    }

}

class Viewer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    downloadJSON() {
        const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/sample_data';
        console.log("Downloaded the JSON File from the Server")
        get(url)
            .then(
                (res) => { return res }
            )

    }

    JSONToHTML(jsondata) {
        return jsondata.map(item => Line)
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.JSONToHTML(this.downloadJSON()).html}</p>
                <p>OK</p>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Viewer
```

Comment: `JSONToHTML` accepts a promise from `downloadJSON`, so you'll need to refactor to use `await` or use `.then` in the callback.

Comment: And map is defined indeed, but jsondata IS undefined (that is what error means) since you are passing it from nowhere. I would add another then in downloadJSON and do map there.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from `downloadJSON` so `JSONToHTML` isn't receiving any parameters.  Either wrap the call in a promise and return the promise, or make the function `async`, `await` the axios call, then return the data.  Either way, you have to return something from the main body of `downloadJSON` (either `return get.then(response => response)` or, inside of an `async` method, `return response.data`) in order for `JSONToHTML` to receive a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers. I resolved this problem without using async, await, or a Promise. The culprit was not wrapping the downloadJSON function in componentDidMount.